# Singleton object per user in java web app

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

My Enterprise application requires an Singleton ShoppingCart object(per user),this cart object should not be technically static(which may lead to memory leak).

do i need to make changes to the code (or) apply any pattern to the web application, to achieve singleton per user?

```
public final class ShoppingCartSingleTon {

    private static ShoppingCartSingleTon instance = null;

    private ShoppingCartSingleTon() {}

    public static ShoppingCartSingleTon getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(ShoppingCartSingleTon.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ShoppingCartSingleTon();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: That really wouldn't be a singleton then, would it? Sounds like a normal class at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cart is usually stored in the session of the user. So the cart should be SessionScoped or ViewScoped.

You can include it via injection (cdi, autowired, ...). Spring and JavaEE have these well documented.

In a Web Application where multiple users can access the backend nothing should be static except explicitly wanted. It may cause massive synchronization and concurrency problems.

Comment: may i know, what are some best books for " java EE best practises", you have gone across?

Comment: I just use the web to get confused - just use google with javaee 7 and you get tutorials and documentations and sample code.